# Changing a standard text input into a jquery calendar popup using webform module in Drupal?

Tags: jquery, drupal, module, calendar, drupal-webform

I have a simple booking form in Drupal created using the webform module. I wanted to change the date / time fields from texboxes to a Calendar popup. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

This has been an ongoing feature request for `webform`. But, [jeffschuler](http://drupal.org/user/239714) posted a patch at http://drupal.org/node/71131#comment-1889636 that might work for you.

It uses the `jquery_ui` module and the `date` module, so you'll need to have those installed.